# Unable to select the very first option of multi-select values which are being passed

Tags: java, selenium, salesforce

I am trying to select multiple values in a multi select picklist. I am able to select the multiple values but the very first value which is being passed is not selected.

HTML CODE:

```html
<ul lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical" data-source-list="" id="source-list-315" aria-describedby="keyboard-interacton-315" aria-labelledby="source-list-label-315" aria-multiselectable="true" role="listbox"
  aria-disabled="false">
  <li lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-listbox__item" role="presentation">
    <div lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="0" data-index="0" data-value="APAC"><span lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-media__body"><span lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-truncate" title="APAC">APAC</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-listbox__item" role="presentation">
    <div lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-index="1" data-value="EMEA"><span lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-media__body"><span lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-truncate" title="EMEA">EMEA</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-listbox__item" role="presentation">
    <div lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-index="2" data-value="LATAM"><span lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-media__body"><span lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-truncate" title="LATAM">LATAM</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-listbox__item" role="presentation">
    <div lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-index="3" data-value="US"><span lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-media__body"><span lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-truncate" title="US">US</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-listbox__item" role="presentation">
    <div lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media slds-media_small slds-media_inline" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-index="4" data-value="Canada"><span lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-media__body"><span lightning-duallistbox_duallistbox="" class="slds-truncate" title="Canada">Canada</span></span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
//Code written by me.
List<WebElement> options = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
    WebElement region = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@role=\"listbox\"]/li["+i+"]/div"));
    options.add(region);
    region = null;
}

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL)
        .click(options.get(0))
        .click(options.get(1))
        .click(options.get(3))
        .keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL)
        .build()
        .perform();
```

[image]

The first value i.e  .click(options.get(0)) is not selected.

Can someone help me over here as I am stuck in this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

@Mansi Palav, Since I do not have the entire web page, not able to debug why it is not selecting the first one. But you can get all the elements at one go without using for loop as given below. Let me know if this works:

```
List<WebElement> regions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']/li/div"));

Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).click(regions.get(0)).click(regions.get(1)).click(regions.get(3))
        .keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).build().perform();
```

You will have to add the following import:

```
import java.util.List;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for optimizing my code but still not able to select the first value which we will pass.

Comment: @Mansi Palav Is it possible to share the url so I can try

Comment: Ya sure. I think it will ask for username nd password https://palav-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Account/new?count=1&nooverride=1&useRecordTypeCheck=1&navigationLocation=LIST_VIEW&uid=166385529298093388&backgroundContext=%2Flightning%2Fo%2FAccount%2Flist%3FfilterName%3DRecent&recordTypeId=0122w000001EOPEAA4

Comment: @Mansi Palav, I do not have access. Another possible reason is that by default, the first item is selected, and when you try to click again, it gets deselected. Can you check this? i..e. remove the part `click(regions.get(0))`

Comment: Ya I did that as well so if I remove click(regions.get(0)). The next one behaves the same  i.e click(options.get(1)) This becomes non selected.